# What is the input voltage range for this voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

This regulator is used to obtain a 3V3 output voltage. http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf2/78/81/788153/ld1117axx.pdf

What is the acceptable input voltage range for this regulator? I cannot get a clear answer from the datasheet. Would using an DC input of 12V,1.5A be safe?

Comment: May I ask why the negative votes? What is wrong with the question? Will appreciate if I know why so that I can improve on my future questions.

Comment: Who knows. It is so rude to vote down without stating a reason unless a really poor quality question. Was  1.5A just your source limit because you cannot output 1.5A @ 3.3V with 18W going in this little chip.  with such a large voltage drop.   But it can easily work for you with the heatsink and thermal precautions up to 0.5A  Its only 30 cents or so more than the UA78 series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use an [UA78M33](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua78m05.pdf) rather than a '1117. They're rated for 25V in (35V abs max) and are inexpensive and very stable. Your 12V is above the recommended maximum (10V) but below the absolute max (15V) so you're still in a danger zone- if the 12V supply overshoots a bit you could see failures.

There's no point in using an LDO where you are burning away 8.7V anyway- your efficiency will necessarily be terrible with a linear regulator.

If the current drawn is more than a few tens of mA, you should consider using a switching regulator instead.

If you insist on using the '1117 you can drop the input voltage a bit with a series zener + resistor to maintain minimum current, or maybe a series LED + resistor to ground (for the same reason) if the currents are small and light variation with current doesn't bother you.

The resistors can be either from the input diode to ground or from the output of the regulator to ground, depending on where you want the power to be dissipated.

Answer (score 2):

10 V. The parameter you are looking for is "VI Operating input voltage."

Comment: What if I can only find a DC input 12V jack? The maximum rating is 20V. Would 12V be safe?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute maximum input voltage is 15V.

However, the output voltage is only specified for input voltages up to 10V; that is, if `Vin` is less than 10V then `Vout` will be between 3.168V and 3.432V, which is +/-4% of the rated output.

The output for a 12V input is therefore not guaranteed by the manufacturer.

You also need to consider the current being drawn by the load. The 1A capability is only specified for a `Vin-Vout` of 5V - so an input of no more than 8.3V in your case. This equates to 5 Watts consumed by the regulator; if you increase the voltage difference between the input and output you must reduce the maximum current you draw with the load so that the regulator always has less than 5W to dissipate.

There is no harm in using a 'pre-regulator' if you need to draw currents that flirt with the maximum rating. An 8V regulator (perhaps created from an adjustable version) will allow the voltages to be dropped in stages, thus sharing the dissipated power across two devices. I would say that this is preferable to using two 3.3V regulators in parallel as equal sharing of current cannot be guaranteed.